# Analytical formula for distribution of partial sum of standardized random variable

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, bootstrap, standardization

I would like to know if there is an analytical formula for the distribution of partial sums of standardized random variables. (Of course, if one standardizes a random variable, the sum of *all* the individual observations will be zero).

I have written a Python function that estimates quantiles by bootstrapping. Each bootstrap iteration consists of three steps:

1. `n` samples of a Normal(0, 1) random variable are generated.
2. The resulting sample is then standardized.
3. The sum of the first `k` elements of the standardized sample is calculated.

This procedure is followed `niter` times, generating a sample of size `niter`. The quantiles of this sample are then calculated.

In case it helps, here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats.mstats

def boot_standardized(n, k, niter=1000, prob=None):
    if prob is None:
        prob = [0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.95]

    x = np.random.randn(n, niter)
    x_std = (x - np.mean(x, axis=0))/np.std(x, axis=0)

    boot_values = np.sum(x_std[:k,:], axis=0)

    return scipy.stats.mstats.mquantiles(boot_values, prob=prob)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, there is a formula in the specific situation given.**  This situation concerns $n$ independent standard Normal variables $\mathrm{X}= (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ that model a sample of size $n.$  Standardization converts them to $Z_1, \ldots, Z_n$ where

$$Z_i = \frac{X_i - m}{s}$$

and, as usual,

$$m = \frac{1}{n}\sum X_i$$

is the sample mean and

$$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum (X_i - m)^2$$

is the sample variance.  The question concerns the distribution of

$$Y_k = \sum_{i=1}^k Z_i.$$

Algebra permits us to write

$$s Y_k = \frac{n-k}{n}\sum_{i=1}^k X_i - \frac{k}{n}\sum_{j=k+1}^n X_j = \mathrm{X} \cdot \omega$$

where $\omega = (\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n)$ is a constant vector whose first $k$ entries are $(n-k)/n$ and last $n-k$ entries are $-k/n.$

**The analysis at [Distribution of scalar products of two random unit vectors in $D$ dimensions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85916) shows the distribution of $Y_k$ must be a multiple of $2U-1$ where $U$ is a Beta$((n-2)/2, (n-2)/2)$ variable.** To find the value of this multiple, we need only compare variances.

The variance of $Y_k$ is readily computed as

$$\operatorname{Var}(Y_k) = ||\omega||^2 = k\left(\frac{n-k}{n}\right)^2 + (n-k)\left(\frac{-k}{n}\right)^2 = \frac{k(n-k)}{n}$$

whereas the variance of $2U-1$ is $1/(n-1).$  Thus,

> $Y_k$ has the distribution of the random variable $$\frac{2U-1}{\sqrt{1/(n-1)}}\sqrt{k(n-k)/n} = (2U-1)\sqrt{\frac{k(n-k)(n-1)}{n}}$$ where $$U \sim \text{Beta}\left(\frac{n}{2}-1, \frac{n}{2}-1\right)$$ for $n \gt 2$ and $0 \le k \le n.$

Equivalently, dividing $Y_k$ by $\sqrt{k(n-k)(n-1)/n}$ produces a variable with the same distribution as $2U-1$ provided $1 \le k \lt n.$

---

To confirm this conclusion, I simulated this construction, inspected histograms of the scaled versions of $Y_k,$ and compared those histograms to the distribution of $2U-1$ by means of a $\chi^2$ test.  The figure displays the results of one simulation of $10,000$ independent datasets for $n=7.$  The headings give the values of $k$ from $1$ through $n-1.$  The red curves plot the density function of $2U-1.$

[image: Figure]

The `R` code that produced this simulation will create many other simulations by varying the values of `n`, `n.sim`, and the random seed in the first three lines.

```
n <- 7
n.sim <- 1e4
set.seed(17)
#
# Simulate samples of size `n` (as columns of `x`) and standardize them.
#
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*n.sim), n)
x <- apply(x, 2, scale) 
#
# Compute sums of k=1, 2, ..., n of the standardized samples and normalize
# them to have variance 1/(n-1).
#
k <- 1:n
y <- apply(x, 2, cumsum) / sqrt(k * (n-k) / n) / sqrt(n-1)

apply(y, 1, var) * (n-1) # Check that variance looks like 1/(n-1)
apply(y, 1, max)         # Verify range is within [-1, 1]
#
# Plot histograms of the normalized sums and compare them to the 
# Beta(n/2-1, n/2-1) distribution supported on [-1,1].
#
breaks <- seq(-1, 1, 0.1)
d.max <- dbeta(1/2, (n-2)/2, (n-2)/2) / 2
n.rows <- floor(sqrt((n-1)))
n.cols <- ceiling((n-1) / n.rows)
par(mfrow=c(n.rows, n.cols))
invisible(lapply(1:(n-1), function(k) {

  #-- Compute a histogram
  h <- hist(y[k, ], breaks=breaks, plot=FALSE)

  #-- Conduct a chi-squared test
  freq <- diff(pbeta((breaks+1)/2, (n-2)/2, (n-2)/2)) * n.sim
  threshold <- min(freq[freq >= 5])
  groups <- 1:length(freq)
  groups[which(freq <= threshold)] <- 0
  X <- aggregate(data.frame(Count=h$counts, Frequency=freq), list(groups), sum)
  a <- with(X, chisq.test(Count, p=Frequency/n.sim))

  #-- Plot the histogram and the comparison distribution
  plot(h, freq=FALSE, ylim=c(0, max(d.max, max(h$density))),
       xlab="Value", main=k, 
       sub=paste0("Chi-squared(", a$parameter["df"], "): p = ", 
                   format(a$p.value, digits=2)))
  curve(dbeta((x+1)/2, (n-2)/2, (n-2)/2) / 2, add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2)
}))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```