# Distribution of Pearson correlation coefficient between two draws from a multinomial

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multinomial-distribution, beta-distribution

As an extension of [this interesting question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85916/distribution-of-scalar-products-of-two-random-unit-vectors-in-d-dimensions), suppose I draw two samples $\mathbf x_1$, $\mathbf x_2$ independently from a $\textrm{Multinomial}(n,\mathbf p)$, with $\mathbf p$ a probability vector of length $k$.

What is the distribution (expectation alone will suffice) of their Pearson correlation coefficient
\begin{align}
r = \frac{(k\mathbf x_1 - n) \cdot (k\mathbf x_2 - n)}{|k\mathbf x_1 - n||k\mathbf x_2 - n|}?
\end{align}

$r^2$ looks to be Beta from simulations, but I can't make much headway with pen and paper.

Comment: It cannot have a Beta distribution for the simple reason that $r^2$ can take only a finite number of possible values, whence its distribution must be *discrete*. If you wish to approximate it, then the quality of the approximation will depend on the entropy of $p$. Thus, the appearance you get in your simulations will not necessarily reveal a general pattern.

Comment: Ah, very good point. A large $n$ approximation would be fine, but I'm pretty stuck on where to go with it.

Comment: Depending on $p$, a large-$n$ approximation should be easy to come by: pretend the data are Normal.