# Distribution of dot products of two random independent unit vectors in $D$ dimensions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, beta-distribution, linear-algebra

[Duplicate of the stats stack exchange question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85916/distribution-of-scalar-products-of-two-random-unit-vectors-in-d-dimensions); however, I need some help with some of the steps in the accepted answer.

> A uniform distribution on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{D-1}$ is
>   obtained by normalizing a $D$-variate normal distribution and the dot
>   product $t$ of normalized vectors is their correlation coefficient
>
> **Method:** The exact distribution of the dot product of unit vectors is
>   easily obtained geometrically, because this is the component of the
>   second vector in the direction of the first. Since the second vector
>   is independent of the first and is uniformly distributed on the unit
>   sphere, its component in the first direction is distributed the same
>   as any coordinate of the sphere. (Notice that the distribution of the
>   first vector does not matter.)
>
> **Finding the Density** Letting that coordinate be the last, the density at $t\in[-1,1]$ is therefore proportional to the surface area lying at a height between $t$ and $t+dt$ on the unit sphere. That proportion occurs within a belt of height $dt$ and radius $\sqrt{1-t^2}$, which is essentially a conical frustum constructed out of an $\mathbb{S}^{D-2}$ of radius $\sqrt{1-t^2}$, of height $dt$, and slope $1/\sqrt{1-t^2}$. Whence the probability is proportional to $\dfrac{\sqrt{1-t^2}^{D-2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt=(1-t^2)^{(D-3)/2}dt$.

I understand that the method detailed above results in a spherical cap and that $t:=cos\theta$, i.e. the dot product between two unit vectors.

Using the Pythagorean theorem, we know that the radius of the base of the cap is $sin\theta=\sqrt{1-cos^2\theta}=\sqrt{1-t^2}$.

1) Now is the slope/slant of the "conical frustum":  $\dfrac{\textrm{radius of the unit. sphere}}{\textrm{radius of the cap base}}$, i.e. $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$?

2) And is the thickness of the conical frustum $R\cdot dt=dt$, where $R=1$ (unit $n$-sphere radius)?

3) I understand that the surface area of $\mathbb{S}^{D-1}$ with radius $R$ is proportional to $R^{D-1}$. But, how do we get the proportional probability?

Comment: I lost you at "We have the spherical cap area:" none of those equalities seems to comport with the laws of Euclidean geometry.  Could you perhaps provide explanations for the steps you are taking?

Comment: @whuber I've updated my question