# Probabilities concerning n-spheres

Tags: probability, distributions, uniform-distribution, beta-distribution, linear-algebra

Let $S_{n-1}(R)=\{ {\bf x}\in {\mathbb{R}}^n : ||{\bf x}||^2=R^2\}$ be the sphere in ${\mathbb{R}}^n$ with radious $R>0.$ Let the projection map $\tau_m({\bf x})=(x_1,...,x_m)$ with $m\leq n.$ Now, if ${\bf x}=(x_1,...,x_n)$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere $S_{n-1}(1)$ (we write it as ${\bf x}\sim_{\mathcal{U}} S_{n-1}(1) )$ then the probability $||\tau_m({\bf x})||^2\leq r^2 \ (r<R)$ is
$${\mathbb{P}}_n(1,r) = I_{a,b}(r^2),$$ where $a=m/2, b=(n-m)/2$ and $I_{a,b}(x)$ is the [regularized incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function). This is because $||\tau_m({\bf x})||^2=\sum_{j=1}^{m} x_j^2$ follows the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) ${\rm Beta}({a=\frac{m}{2},b=\frac{n-m}{2}})$ see [Lemma 1,Ref. 1].

My question concerns the computation of the following probabilities :
First what will happen if ${\bf x}$ follows uniform distribution in $S_{n-1}(R)$ for some $R>0,$ i.e.
$${\mathbb{P}}_n(R,r) = Pr\Big({\bf x}=(x_i)\sim_{{\mathcal{U}}} S_{n-1}(R) :  ||\tau_m({\bf x})||^2\leq r^2 \Big)$$
and
${\mathbb{P}}_n(1;r_1,r_2)=$
$$Pr\Big({\bf x}=(x_i)\sim_{{\mathcal{U}}} S_{n-1}(1) : ||\tau_m({\bf x})||^2\leq r_1^2, ||\tau_{\ell}({\bf x})||^2\leq r_2^2\ \text{where} \ (m>\ell, r_1>r_2)\Big)$$
How can I compute them?

---

Ref. 1 : [Radoslav Harman,Vladimír Lacko, On decompositional algorithms for uniform sampling from n-spheres and n-balls](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X10001211)

---

**An example**
Say that ${\bf x}$ is uniformly distribute in $S_{2}(1),$ i.e. the unit sphere in ${\mathbb{R}}^3.$ We ask, what is the probability $x_1^2+x_2^2\leq  2/3$ and $x_1^2\leq 1/3.$ Monte Carlo simulation shows that this event has probability $\frac{1}{3}.$ That is ${\mathbb{P}}_3(1;\sqrt\frac{2}{3},\sqrt\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{3}.$ In fact by inspection we get $${\mathbb{P}}_n\Big(1;\sqrt\frac{n-1}{n},\sqrt\frac{n-2}{n},\cdots,\sqrt\frac{1}{n}\Big) = \frac{1}{n}.$$
**EDIT 1** From a comment of Whuber easily we can compute the first probability $${\mathbb{P}}_n(R;r) = {\mathbb{P}}_n(1;r/R).$$

---

Comment: What are the back arrows with dollar signs over them intended to mean?  Why do you need two subscripts on "$x$"?  BTW, an immediately accessible account of the material from your reference appears right here at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85916.

Comment: I removed the second subscript from ${\bf x}$ and $ means randomly (is used mainly in cryptography). Thanks for the reference, but It does not seem to help me to my problem, but it is interesting.

Comment: I still struggle to understand your notation.  It appears to ask for a conditional probability, but in this setting all those probabilities are zero.  Maybe you are looking for some kind of conditional *density* function?

Comment: why they are zero? I computed the second probability using monte carlo. Although you are right that I have to compute a conditional probability.

Comment: Because the distributions are continuous, so the probabilities you appear to be asking for are finite multiples of the area of a point, which is zero.

Comment: do not follow you. I think the probability is a multiple of the area of $S_{n-1}$

Comment: Well, that's exactly the problem: because you use an unusual notation, it's likely to be misinterpreted.  Please include an explanation in your question so that your readers will have a better chance of understanding what you're asking.

Comment: I am still puzzled by your notation, because (as I understand it) a change of units of measurement to make $R$ one unit on the new scale shows $\mathbb{P}_n(R,r)=\mathbb{P}_n(1,r/R),$ rendering the first question trivial.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: No, I think you are right