# Additivity of angles in higher dimensions

Tags: normal-distribution, high-dimensional

Suppose $x_i$'s are IID random samples from $d$-dimensional isotropic Gaussian centered at zero and normalized to have $E[\|x\|^2]=1$

Suppose we have
$$a=x_1 \\ b=a+x_2 \\ c=b+x_3$$

As $d$ increases, the following is observed

$$\cos(a,c) \approx \cos(a,b)\cos(b,c)$$

Where
$$\cos(x,y)=\frac{\langle x, y\rangle}{\|x\| \|y\|}$$

Why?

[image]

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/stats.SE-cosines.nb)

individual cosine distribution:

[image]

We can continue this pprocess with $d=c+x_4$, $e=d+x_5$, and this "three-way" cosine similarity seems to approach integer values among all triplets of vectors
[image]

Comment: What do the distributions of the individual cosines look like?

Comment: added to ..... post

Comment: Thanks -- i should have asked, more specifically, do the individual cosine distributions narrow woth increasing d, and is there a sense in which the variance of the cosine ratio is narrower than the variance of the cosine distributions themselves?

Comment: they all seem to shrink at about the same rate

Comment: As $d$ increases, it becomes increasingly likely that any set of such Normal variates is nearly mutually orthogonal.  Go on from there.  BTW, your formula for the cosine is incorrect--the denominator should not be squared.  Are you using the correct formula in your computations or the one you have posted?  I think this result relies on using the wrong formula, which reduces (asymptotically) to the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: good catch, removing the square makes it easier to interpret -- cosines are just multiplicative in this setting $\cos(a,c)=\cos(a,b)\cos(b,c)$

Comment: ... and that is because asymptotically the cosines are all $1.$  And because they all have Beta distributions, you can obtain more precise asymptotics if you like.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/85977/919.

Comment: They are all zero asymptotically, but this relationship requires them to go to zero at a specific rate

Comment: Right--I meant to write "0" instead of "1," corresponding to orthogonality.

Comment: This seems to be more general phenomenon for small perturbations. IE, if instead of "adding random noise" I do a random simple rotation with angle $\theta$, cosines are multiplicative for $\theta\le \frac{\pi}{4}$, whereas $\theta>\frac{\pi}{4}$, this relationship [breaks down](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526950/showing-that-cosu-1-u-3-cosu-1-u-2-cosu-2-u-3-for-nearby-u-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430305/triangle-equality-for-cosine-similarity-in-high-dimensions/430325#430325) on Mathoverflow by Iosif Pinelis. Using Chebychev's inequality he showed that isotropic normal RV's $X,Y,Z$

\begin{equation}
 U:=X,\quad V:=X+Y,\quad W:=X+Y+Z, 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \cos(U,V)=\frac{U\cdot V}{\sqrt{U\cdot U}\sqrt{V\cdot V}}\sim_P\frac1{\sqrt2}, 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \cos(V,W)=\frac{V\cdot W}{\sqrt{V\cdot V}\sqrt{W\cdot W}}\sim_P\frac2{\sqrt6}, 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \cos(U,W)=\frac{U\cdot W}{\sqrt{U\cdot U}\sqrt{W\cdot W}}\sim_P\frac1{\sqrt3}.  
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \cos(U,V)\cos(V,W)\sim_P \cos(U,W). 
\end{equation}